# Problem ranking features on different numerical ranges

Tags: analysis, statistics

What is the best way to find the best individual in a population based on two score values that span different ranges?

For example, say I have a population where each individual has two rating values associated with it: an "attractiveness" rating value on the range 1-10, and an "intelligence" rating on the range 0-0.001. How do I find the individual with the highest combined attractiveness and intelligence?

I could take the geometric mean of the two ratings for each individual and pick the "best" individual based on those resulting scores. Or I could scale each range to [0 1] and sum them to pick a best value. Are there other options? Is there an accepted "correct" way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

There is no single accepted way; what you use depends on what you
deem useful.

Let $x$ and $y$ be the normalized (i.e. in $[0,1]$)
intelligence and attractiveness. Then, one simple possibility is to take
a linear combination of the two:
$$
x+\alpha y
$$
where $\alpha>0$. $\alpha=1$ implies that both attributes are equally
important, while $\alpha\lessgtr1$ weights in favour of one or the
other.